# Limit all postgresql with rails must be integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm just trying out some stuff and I found something interesting, when I try to pass a string argument to the limit method I get an error.

Here is an example :

```
User.where('id > 10000').limit('ALL')
```

The error thrown is :

ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "ALL"

This works of course :

```
User.where('id > 10000').limit(5)
```

But according to postgresql docs, should be possible to pass the ALL as a limit :
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html

And works on simple query from pgadmin that I tried :

```
select id from users limit ALL
```

Is there a workaround for rails with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LIMIT ALL is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause.

I think the postgres docs are pretty clear here. Just remove the limit. i.e.

```
User.where('id > 10000')
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I know I can remove the all clause, I'm just wondering if there is a way to make it work with rails/AR

Comment: make what work? The limit all syntax does not provide functionality that is not available otherwise.

Comment: it is available otherwise, we can all see the obvious. I had a specific question, and looking for specific answer. If there is no answer or you might not know it, that's ok because there is always option of removing the limit I think we all get that.

Comment: Well the answer is there is no way to make active record generate a 'LIMIT ALL' query. (because it's database specific and provides no additional functionality)

Comment: Ok that's seems to be the case for now, I'll accept in a little while